# Should DotA get another Tag synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I would like to suggest that [defense-of-the-ancients2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defense-of-the-ancients2) and [defenseoftheancients2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defenseoftheancients2) as a synonym for [dota2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dota2).

Comment: [tag:defense-of-the-ancients] is already a synonym for [tag:dota]: https://i.3ventic.eu/20140325121129259.png

Comment: And given that, "defenseoftheancients" should suggest the hyphenated version anyway.

Comment: @RavenDreamer it doesn't, though.

Comment: @3ventic When typing it out? It popped up as you start typing defense. I see no merit in having the tag without hyphens, since the hyphenated version will be suggested as the unhyphenated version is typed out.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I guess I type too quickly, but I agree that the benefit of it isn't great.

Comment: Sorry i was watching the wrong tag. i watched the dota2 tag.

Answer (score 9):

Even though it's strange, technically speaking, Dota 2's name is just that: plain old "Dota 2." Despite its lineage, the proper name of the game is not intended to be an abbreviation for "Defense of the Ancients 2." Valve solely refers to the game as "Dota 2," and you won't find a single reference to "Defense of the Ancients 2" or even "DotA 2" in any sort of official capacity.

From Wikipedia:

> Erik Johnson addressed the confusion over the written form of the brand name, citing it as "Dota", rather than "DotA", due to its increasing context as a concept, rather than an acronym for "Defense of the Ancients".

So, I think that while a "defense-of-the-ancients-2" tag synonym could theoretically help someone (maybe?) who couldn't find the [dota-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dota-2) tag for some reason, it would technically be incorrect.

Comment: This is wrong. Blizzard and Valve had a legal dispute over the name "Defense of the ancients". They settled their dispute with the rule that valve would not be allowed to use defense of the ancients and instead use the acronym. Thats why valve tells us that they do not see dota as defense of the ancients and instead as a context/concept.

Comment: So it was a legal issue rather then a concept one. For further info search for "valve blizzard dota" and "valve blizzard defense of the ancients"

Comment: Right, but my point is that Valve's game isn't called "Defense of the Ancients 2," it's called "Dota 2," so a tag to that effect isn't justified. The exact history as to _how_ Valve arrived at the decision to call their game simply "Dota 2" is sort of ancillary to the point being discussed here.

Comment: "So, I think that while a "defense-of-the-ancients-2" tag synonym could theoretically help someone (maybe?) who couldn't find the [tag:dota-2] tag for some reason, it would technically be incorrect." I agree, but I wonder which comes first for adding a synonym or redirect* of a "defense-of-the-ancients-2" tag: it's syntactic correctness for clarity of those who already understand it (and are probably using [tag:dota-2] anyway), or a synonymous tag creation to help someone who just logged on to ask a question and needs all the help they can get?